# How to get the value of field in backend model of another field in magento 2 admin configuration?

Tags: magento2

How to get the value of field in backend mo[image]del of another field in magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
use \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class MyModel extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
    {
    protected $scopeConfig;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
     array $data = []
    ) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
    public function getMyValue(){
    $myvalue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/mystoreconfigname', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    return $myvalue;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  i want to get the value before custom configuration save. i want to get the api token from my site giving username and password on magento configuration. i need username/pwd field values in backend model